# docker build with inline fails

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am trying to build a docker image with inline commands, it goes well until copy statement where it fails saying it cannot find the file. When I put the build statements in Dockerfile and run build, it works fine.

```
docker build -t casspy -<<EOF
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk -v add python3 py-pip bash && \
    pip install ldap3 cassandra-driver configargparse boto3
COPY script.py .
EOF

Step 3/3 : COPY script.py .
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder451609694/script.py: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a specify a build context for docker.

*Omitting the build context can be useful in situations where your Dockerfile does not require files to be copied into the image, and improves the build-speed, as no files are sent to the daemon.*
https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

```
docker build -t casspy -f- . <<EOF
```

Comment: Doesn't help, same error...unless I use Dockerfile. Without the copy, inline build works but with copy it fails.

Comment: Add output. Do you build it in the command line or in the other tool?